# Curl giving unauthorized response in production but not in localhost

Tags: php, curl

I am using Curl to get contents of a website but I'm getting a `403 access denied` response on production. However, on my local machine (localhost), it works fine.

I'm essentially using Curl to login to a website and then access the content after login.

I think it has something to do with setting headers but I'm not quite sure, since the headers work on localhost.

Here's my code for the curl request:

```
    $email = "email@example.com";
    $password = "password";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL  => 'https://auth.example.com/ajax/',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,

        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => "email=$email&password=$password",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => 0,
        CURLOPT_REFERER        => 'https://my-website.com',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2117.157 Safari/537.36',
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    ];

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

    curl_exec($ch);

    //change URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/logged-in");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    // do stuff with content
```

I'm also very interested in how this works in localhost and not in production.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The remote site might be blacklisting your web host.

Comment: You should contact the website operator to find out why they're blocking your web host.

Answer (score 0):

Your cookie jar is likely not writable by the server user in your production environment. [Libcurl can't throw an error about this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html), so you're getting a 403 when your second request fires.

If you have command line access, run `chmod 777` on your script's directory to test it. If it works, fix up your webserver permissions and undo the `777` permissions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using DigitalOcean and Laravel and I still can't get the cookie.txt file to be created. I tried `chmod 777` but it still doesn't create the file.

Comment: You need to put your script directory in there. Do a `sudo chmod 777 /my/script/directory/`. Failing that, try `cd /my/script/directory` then `touch cookie.txt` then `sudo chmod 777 cookie.txt`.

Comment: I tried doing `chmod 777 cookie.txt` but that didn't work. Does the script itself need to be 777 as well?

Comment: No, the script shouldn't have `777` permissions set. In fact, as soon as we've worked this out you should change them back. Are you able to give us a pastebin of the results of `ls -lah` on the script directory?

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/rRUmVe5U The cookie.txt file is not being created automatically

Comment: Could you do the same for your local environment? Perhaps the cookie file is in a different directory.

Comment: The local env actually has 755. And regardless of where the directory is for the `cookie.txt` file, it's always generated and works. I think the main issue is that the `cookie.txt` file is not created in production at all, no matter how I try. Is this some sort of restriction that I have to set on `php.ini` file?

Comment: Well, it seems like that's probably a good starting point for fixing the issue regardless. What do the logs in `[webroot]/storage/logs` have to say about it?